# SWIG + setup.py: ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_foo)

Tags: python, c++, linux, python-2.7, swig

I am trying to wrap a function foo in `test.cpp` with swig. I have a header `foo.h` which contains the declaration of the function foo. `test.cpp` is dependent upon a external header `ex.h` and shared object file `libex.so` located in `/usr/lib64`

I followed the [blog post from here](http://bitsofpy.blogspot.com/2009/05/swig-with-c-and-external-libs.html).

I am able to build the module with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. However when I try to import it I get the following error and I am not sure what I am missing as most others questions with this error do not use a `setup.py` file. Below is an example of what I currently have.

**The Error on importing _foo:**

```
>>> import _foo

ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_foo)
```

**test.i**

```
%module foo


%{
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "test.h"
%}

%include <std_vector.i>
%include <std_string.i>
%include "test.h"
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "ex.h"

void foo(int i){
    return;
};
```

**test.h**

```
#include "ex.h"

void foo(int i);
```

**setup.py**

```
try:
    from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext
    from setuptools import setup, Extension, Command
except:
    from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
    from distutils import setup, Extension, Command

foo_module = Extension('_foo', 
                        sources=['foo.i' , 'foo.cpp'],
                        swig_opts=['-c++'],
                        library_dirs=['/usr/lib64'],
                        libraries=['ex'],
                        include_dirs = ['/usr/include'],
                        extra_compile_args = ['-DNDEBUG', '-DUNIX', '-D__UNIX',  '-m64', '-fPIC', '-O2', '-w', '-fmessage-length=0'])

setup(name='mymodule',
      ext_modules=[foo_module],
      py_modules=["foo"],
      )
```

Comment: are you seeing it generate a  wrap file compiling the generated file and linking that into the module? Something like `swig -python -c++ -o foo_wrap.cpp foo.i`, `gcc ... foo_wrap.cpp ...`,  `g++ ... foo_wrap.o ...` as in the output in the blog post cited

Comment: @Thomas Yes there is a long/similar output I'll post what I'm seeing in a moment.

Comment: @Thomas here's the output, http://pastebin.com/MSChdNMy

Comment: Hmm looks good. Is there an `init_foo` method in the `foo_wrap.cpp`? Is there an `init_foo` symbol in `_foo.so`?

Comment: @Thomas thanks! your comment on looking at the symbols lead me to the answer I had the wrong module name in my interface file.

Comment: @Thomas make an answer so I can reward you the bonus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is looks like there is some inconsistency in the use of `foo` and `_foo`, as the wrap file is generated compiled and linked in.

Try changing the module name in `test.i` from

```
%module foo
```

to

```
%module _foo
```

or adjusting the Extension declaration in your `setup.py` from

```
Extension('_foo',
```

to

```
Extension('foo',
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, however it was due to which python was being in use. I was using a system with python2.7, python3.4 and python3.5. Only "python3" (symlinked to python3.5) worked. Importing with any of the other pythons gave the " ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function" error.